# Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file

Tags: windows

Whenever I try to launch Visual Studio Code I get the Error "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."
I have tried to check the permissions on the file but it says I do not have high enough permissions. I am on a administrator account and I have tried running it as admin too.
It does this every time I close it and everytime I have to uninstall it then reinstall it to fix it.

Comment: Same problem here